# How to combine the results of individual domains in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How to combine the results of individual domains in Google Analytics?

I currently am setting up Google Analytics for sites on .com .de and .cn. I have different Google Analytics profiles set up for each and would like to be able to combine the results as a whole to view from that perspective as well without putting them into a spreadsheet. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Like previously stated, I don't know of a way to back date this. However, there's a bit of a hack, assuming I'm understanding you correctly and your domains are on different profiles, not different properties. If that's the case you should be using a single tracking code for all your domains under one property, with each domain being it's own profile. 
In this case your 'rollup' profile would be a profile with no filter on it. Meanwhile, each of the individual domains would contain a filter to just track that one domain. The profile without any filters would collect all the data and the profiles with filters would only collect the data from the domain you specified in the filter. 
This doesn't rollup properties, but does rollup profiles.

edit: found a post about it
http://moz.com/ugc/single-google-analytics-tracking-code-for-multiple-sites-when-to-use-how-to-report

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to ad-hoc combine data from multiple profiles in GA.  The current standard to get rollup reporting is that in addition to each site having its own profile, you should also set up a "master" (rollup) profile that receives data from all of your sites. Here is a link to the GA docs explaining the setup:

[Key Components to Cross-Domain Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=en#keyComponents)

Unfortunately, GA does not provide a way to apply all this retroactively or import historical data to the profile, so you're going to have to go the "export to a spreadsheet and do magic there" route for historical data :(

Comment: Note that you should be using multiple "tracking ids" or properties and not multiple profiles.

Comment: @Avi  No, you should be using a single account id, create multiple profiles, and create include or exclude filters based on domain. You cannot make a rollup profile across multiple accounts.

Comment: hmm. I was thinking more like using separate properties/account id to send hits for individual accounts and then having a second tracker on all the pages that acts as a roll up account. Won't that work? Adding it as a separate answer since you point out that this is not what you meant.

Comment: It would work, but at best is less efficient. See my comment on your answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

One of the ways is described by @Crayon. The other thing you can do is:

For each of your sites, create a different account. **Track all the general stuff on the site-specific accounts. In addition to that, Create a new web property which is used to create a second tracker on all the sites** and is used as a roll up property.

The benefits of this approach are:

- You get to track different things on roll-up account and on individual account.
- On the roll up account, you can ignore certain domains if needed.
- You don't have to muck around with filters.

Comment: Doubling up on on-page code does not sound like an efficient way to go about this...it's increased page load time, and also having to work with separate namespaces or worry about overwriting. point #1: you get that from my (which is GA's official) way.  point #2: you can do that with filters anyway. But that sort of misses the point in a rollup profile. #3: working with filters is a lot easier than working with on-page code. It's a lot easier to implement and maintain, especially if you have to go through other people to update on-page code (which happens a lot in companies)

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for GA Premium users: you could try to set-up "roll-up reporting" (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6033415).

Answer (score 0):

Usually  you can view a table with the different hostnames/domain not sure if this is what you want. https://www.fourfront.us/blog/using-the-hostname-filter-for-accurate-google-analytics-data